Calculating $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\mathrm{e}^{-x^{2}}}{\left(x^{2}+1/2\right)^{2}}\mathrm{d}x$ using residue method
I'm calculating a definite integral like
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\mathrm{e}^{-x^{2}}}{\left(x^{2}+1/2\right)^{2}}\mathrm{d}x
$$
actually, there are lots of answers about this problem, but I want
to try another method by residue. suppose
$$
C_{1}=[-R,R],\ C_{2}=\left\{ R\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\theta}:0\le\theta\le\pi\right\} ,
$$
then I get
\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\mathrm{e}^{-x^{2}}}{\left(x^{2}+1/2\right)^{2}}\mathrm{d}x & =\frac{1}{2}\lim_{R\to+\infty}\int_{C_{1}}\frac{\mathrm{e}^{-z^{2}}}{\left(z^{2}+1/2\right)^{2}}\mathrm{d}z\\
 & =\frac{1}{2}\lim_{R\to+\infty}\oint_{C_{1}+C_{2}}\frac{\mathrm{e}^{-z^{2}}}{\left(z^{2}+1/2\right)^{2}}\mathrm{d}z\\
 & =\frac{1}{2}\cdot2\pi\mathrm{i}\mathrm{Res}\left(\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}z}\frac{\mathrm{e}^{-z^{2}}}{\left(z+\sqrt{2}\mathrm{i}/2\right)^{2}},\frac{\sqrt{2}\mathrm{i}}{2}\right)={\color{red}0}.
\end{align*}
What curious me is that the residue is zero, which contradict the
result $\sqrt{\pi}$.
Some further calculation in the above derivation
$$
\left|\int_{C_{2}}\frac{\mathrm{e}^{-z^{2}}}{\left(z^{2}+1/2\right)^{2}}\mathrm{d}z\right|=\left|\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{\mathrm{e}^{-R^{2}\mathrm{e}^{2\mathrm{i}\theta}}}{\left(R^{2}\mathrm{e}^{2\mathrm{i}\theta}+1/2\right)^{2}}R\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\theta}\mathrm{i}\mathrm{d}\theta\right|\lesssim\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{1}{R}\mathrm{d}\theta\to0,\quad R\to+\infty.
$$

Your estimation of the integral over $C_2$ looks suspicious to me, $\exp(-z^2)$ grows exponentially on the imaginary axis.

At $R i \in C_2$, the integrand has value
$$\frac{e^{R^2}}{\left(R^2 - \frac12\right)^2},$$ which behaves like $R^{-4} e^{R^2}$ and so diverges to $\infty$ as $R \to \infty$. In particular, the inequality in the last display equation in the question statement is not correct.

Oh, yes, thanks, what a silly mistake i make... so the method of residue should not possible to continue...

Not with this family of contours, at least.
